# keystore while loading : An IO Exception has occurred: Error in loading the keystore: DerValue.getOctetString, not an Octet String:

Tags: keystore

An IO Exception has occurred:
Error in loading the keystore: DerValue.getOctetString, not an Octet String:

I have script which generate 3 files. but when i run the script in unix like ./scriptname keystore.p12 'password' but at the same password is correct and i have validated as well

I am getting error below :
An IO Exception has occurred:
Error in loading the keystore: DerValue.getOctetString, not an Octet String: